# How to get class Object from database through serializable method

Tags: java, sql, database, serialization, ooad

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Method 'executeQuery(String)' not allowed on prepared statement.

```
public Object getObject() throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        PreparedStatement ps;
        String sql="select * from student";
        ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(sql);
        Student newStudent=null;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            try (ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(rs.getBytes("description"))) {
                ObjectInputStream obis;
                obis = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
                newStudent=(Student)obis.readObject();
            }
        }
        return newStudent;

    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You should execute query in `Prepared Statement` as

```
ps.executeQuery(); //Without parameter
```

If you read the documentation for `executeQuery(String)`, it is clearly mentioned,

> Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet object.
>   **Note:**This method cannot be called on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement